# (Installshield 2010) ISProject Folder in TFS 2008

Tags: installshield-2010

I wonder what the ISProjectFolder, ISProductFolder, ISProjectDataFolder, ISPROJECTDIR (predefined paths) values are assigned when I build using TFS 2008 build agent

I think these can have different values from the values that are seen on local

does anyone know about this????

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  task to 'dump' the values you describe to the build log, i.e :

```
    <!--Copy the installer files into the distribution location.-->
    <Message Text="PATH TO SERVER INSTALL SET : $(ISServerOutputToBeCopied)" />
    <exec command="xcopy &quot;$(ISServerOutputToBeCopied)&quot; &quot;\\jupiter\Albany Products\In Development\EFT Corporate\ePay 1.5 Releases\1.5.$(AlbanyServicePackNumber)\$(BuildNumber)\ePay Server Installer&quot; /i /s /e /h /y" />
</Target>

<!--Build the "ePay Client" Installer project.-->
<Target Name="CompileISClientProject"
            DependsOnTargets="CustomCoreDropBuild"
            Condition="('$(InstallShieldIsCmdBldPath)' != '') And ('@(ISClientProjectFile)' != '') And ('$(InstallShieldProductConfiguration)' != '' ) And ('$(InstallShieldRelease)' != '')">
    <exec Command="&quot;$(InstallShieldIsCmdBldPath)&quot; -p &quot;@(ISClientProjectFile)&quot; -c &quot;$(InstallShieldProductConfiguration)&quot; -r &quot;$(InstallShieldRelease)&quot; -z &quot;ARPCOMMENTS=$(BuildNumber)&quot; -y &quot;$(AlbanyMajorNumber).$(AlbanyMinorNumber).$(AlbanyServicePackNumber).$(AlbanyBuildNumber)&quot;" IgnoreExitCode="true" />

    <!--Copy the installer files into the distribution location.-->
    <Message Text="PATH TO CLIENT INSTALL SET : $(ISClientOutputToBeCopied)" />
    <exec command="xcopy &quot;$(ISClientOutputToBeCopied)&quot; &quot;\\jupiter\Albany Products\In Development\EFT Corporate\ePay 1.5 Releases\1.5.$(AlbanyServicePackNumber)\$(BuildNumber)\ePay Client Installer&quot; /i /s /e /h /y" />
</Target>
```

Hope that helps !